# ASP.Net Core try to implement Select2 multi-select dropdown with Ajax

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I make an ASP.net core application. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and I have the following tables with many to many relations.

```
public class Store : BaseDeletableModel<int>
{
    public Store()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<StoreTag>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<StoreTag> Tags { get; set; }
}




    public class Tag : BaseDeletableModel<int>
{
    public Tag()
    {
        this.StoreTags = new HashSet<StoreTag>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<StoreTag> StoreTags { get; set; }
}





    public class StoreTag : BaseDeletableModel<int>
{
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

In the following API controller class TagsController, in the method GetAllByTerm() I need to pass the value of term which, in this case, should be Tag name and Tag Id , сo I can work at the дата base.

```
[Route("Api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TagsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDeletableEntityRepository<Tag> repository;

    public TagsController(IDeletableEntityRepository<Tag> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllByTerms(string term)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
        {
            var data = this.repository
                .AllAsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
                .ToList();

            return Ok(data);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

}

With the following query using Select2 I'm trying to implement a multi-select dropdown. At the moment the script reads the tags from the database displays them and I can add them to the multi-select window. What I'm trying to do is for these values to be passed to the API controller class TagsController to the method GetAllByTerm(), so I can work with them in the database.

```
$("#ajaxMultiSelect2").select2({
placeholder: "Select Multiple Values",
theme: "bootstrap4",
allowClear: true,
ajax: {
    url: "/Api/Tags",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: function (params) {
        var query =
        {
            term: params.term,
        };
        return query;
    },
    processResults: function (result) {
        return {
            results: $.map(result, function (item) {
                return {
                    id: item.id,
                    text: item.name
                };
            }),
        };
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Hi @steko, Do you misunderstand the `GetAllByTerms` method? When you enter a letter in select2 dropdown search input, it will get into your `/Api/Tags` GetAllByTerms method with the term=your enter letter value.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have big misunderstandings about the method. Just for the first time, I'm trying to add to the database this way. May I ask for some guidance on how this can happen, I will be very grateful.